# ¿Diferencia entre persist() y save() hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estoy queriendo guardar un UsuarioExterno este es mi controlador que interactúa con la `BD` [image]

La cosa que cuando quiero guardar un `UsuarioExterno` con todos sus documentos
me aparece este error.

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist

Lo estuve investigando y me di cuenta que en mi constructor estoy insertando un Objeto `"tipo_documento"` que ya existe en la `bd` y no lo vuelve a crear por que ya esta creado, y `save` solo me guarda El padre de los objetos.Como podría resolverlo

Comment: Este error por lo general sucede en relaciones bidireccionales. Básicamente lo que sucede es que estás tratando de persistir un objeto **que tiene un objeto** como parte de su relación **que no está en sesión**. Si tienes un tipo de cascada `ALL` prueba ponerlo en `MERGE`. La diferencia entre `persist` y `save` es que, básicamente, el primero necesita que el objeto esté sea transient, es decir, esté dentro de una sesión, mientras que el segundo no.

Comment: mi relación  de tipo_documento y documentos es de oneToMany(Cascade={cascade.persist,cascade.merge,cascade.detach}) y documentos hace referencia a un objeto tipo_documento, es este objeto el que provoca error por que ya lo tengo todos los tipos de documentos en la BD solo los llamo para crear un objeto documento y añadirlo a usuarioexterno.

Comment: ya encontré la solución es solo borrar el cascade.persist en el objeto tipo_documento de la clase documento .